# postgres installation error post-bootstrap FATAL: invalid byte sequence

Tags: postgresql, failed-installation

I'm trying to install Postgres 13 (Windows version), but I always obtain same error (part is in Spanish):

> realizando inicializaci¢n **post-bootstrap ... 2021-04-30 12:10:54.935 CEST [1224] FATAL:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xbf**
> el proceso hijo termin¢ con c¢digo de salida 1
> initdb: eliminando el contenido del directorio ®C:/PostgreSQL13/data¯
>
> Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
> Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb
>
> Script stderr:
> Program ended with an error exit code
>
> Error al ejecutar C:\WINDOWS\System32\cscript //NoLogo "C:\PostgreSQL13/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_b86f3c1062" "C:\PostgreSQL13" "C:\PostgreSQL13\data" 5432 "English,UnitedStates" 0 : Program ended with an error exit code
> Problema al ejecutar el paso post instalación. La instalación no pudo finalizar correctamente
> La inicialización del clúster de la base de datos falló.

User user1 has administrator rights. I have also tried to install version 12 instead of 13, but the result is the same.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have experience with the Windows-version of Postgresql but have you verified the codepage installed is UTF-8? Windows will use WINDOWS-1252 in many European countries.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely because the database superuser name contains non-ASCII characters.

I don't know exactly how you install PostgreSQL, but this probably happens when you run `initdb` to create a data directory (which would fit with the "initcluster" script in your message).

If you don't specify a superuser name by using the `-U` option of `initdb` (it is customary to use the nae `postgres`), `initdb` will name the superuser like your current operating system user. If you are on Windows, that name will be encoded in a Windows encoding like Windows-1252. Now the database doesn't know that, and when it creates the database user, it uses the very bytes of that user name. If that is not correctly encoded UTF-8 (which is won't be if it contains non-ASCII characters), that causes this error.

My suggestion is that you log on to Windows with an operating system user that has all ASCII characters in its name and try again.

Comment: Hi Laurenz,

I'm installing postgres with the generic GUI installer Wizard (downloaded from Postgre site), logging on Windows with a user with administrator rights, and the name only contains ascii characters (all consonants and vocals, in fact).

Comment: Hi again Laurenz,

Taking in mind your considerations about user name and ASCII characters, I have tried to install again PostgreSQL changing both passwords for windows user and postgre users to only consonants characters and the installation worked.

I consider an error not allowing more complex password, but it worked. I will try to change passwords againg and I hope it still works.

Comment: Interesting - I think that only the database user's password could be a concern, and even that surprises me. I am sure you can change the database user's password later on to whatever you want.